# JavaScript XHR - get raw response data on non-200 status if responseType was set as json

Tags: javascript, error-handling, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to get the "raw" (text/data) from an `XMLHttpRequest` response if the `responseType` was dynamically set to `json` prior to sending the request?

I suppose it could be done conditionally with another request to the same URL with `overrideMimeType`, but that could be unwise - regarding server logs or any other processes.

Here is an example:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET','/some/path.wtf');
xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.onloadend = function()
{
  if (this.status !== 200)
  {
    console.log(this.response);  // null
    // send the response-text to an error handler .. sigh :(
    return;
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

In the actual code of my project, a request for a "/folder/path/" is regarded as a request for JSON and the server responds with JSON; unless there was an issue, or a `client.console.log()` routine was invoked for debugging/testing.

Any input will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks epascarello, indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution to the problem; however, it is a work-around -but ***may*** be helpful to others facing the same problem:

```js
var pth,ext,rsp,xhr;

pth = '/some/path/';
rsp = ((path.substr(-1) == '/') ? 'json' : 'blob');  // for example
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.patchJSON = ((rsp == 'json') ? 1 : 0);
xhr.open('GET',pth);
xhr.responseType = ((rsp == 'json') ? 'text' : rsp);

xhr.onloadend = function()
{
  if (this.status !== 200)
  {
    console.log(this.response);  // response-text from server
    // send the response-text to an error handler .. yayy :)
    return;
  }

  if (this.patchJSON)
  {
    rsp = JSON.parse(this.response);

    if ((rsp === null) && (this.response.trim().length > 0))
    {
      console.log('json syntax error in: '+pth);
      // send `rsp` to the error handler
      return;
    }
  }

  // handle blobs/markup/etc, -or:
  console.log(rsp);
};

xhr.send();
```